# Changing an element with another element in js

Tags: javascript

I have a button:

```html
<button aria-label="Custom" aria-selected="false" class="ButtonContainer">
  <div class="DivNumContainer">
    <span class="SpanNumDisplay">Custom</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

I want when this button is clicked to change the text "Custom" into a input type box with this code:

```html
<input
  type="number "
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  aria-describedby="error-tip"
  class="InputNum"
  value=""
></input>
```

Any suggestions?

I have tried using this script but didnt work

```js
function repFun() {
  // Creating "input" element
  var H = document.createElement('input type="number " pattern="[0-9]*" aria-describedby="error-tip" class="InputNum" value=""');

  // Creating Text node        
  var txt = document.createTextNode("");

  // Accessing  the Element we want to replace 
  var repNode = document.getElementsByClassName('.SpanNumDisplay');
        
  // Appending Text Node in Element  
  H.appendChild(txt);

  // Replacing one element with another
  repNode.replaceChild(H, repNode.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: To start with: `</input>` is invalid HTML syntax. INPUT is a *void* element (like IMG) and does not have a closing tag. `<div>` inside `<button>` is also invalid markup. Use rather `<span>` if needed.

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do is basically and absolutely an invalid result. You cannot just insert `<input>` into `<button>`. That's also a disallowed markup. Rather (if feasible) **replace** the **entire** button with your new INPUT element.

Comment: The comments above are basically your answer to this question. Back to the drawing board I'm afraid. And - read about the [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) method.

Comment: Remember to [check the docs on functions you use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) because that is **not** how `createElement` works. It's not jQuery, it does not accept a giant HTML string. You give it the tag name and then you set _all those other things_ separately. Also, it's not 2012 anymore, so use `let` or `const`, do not use `var`. The `var` keyword is a legacy keyword for creating hoisted, function scoped variables, instead of normal block scoped variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. You should really just stick to putting text inside a button. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with all div and span stuff, but you can just have the button as:

```
<button ..allyourattrs...>Custom</button>
```

2. You can't create elements like that, adding attributes must be done after the fact (method A). You can however create elements in a similar fashion to your original code by instead creating a temp element and setting its innerHTML (method B).

```
// Method A
const inputElem = document.createElement('input');
inputElem.type = 'number';
... etc

// Method B
const temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = '<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" aria-describedby="error-tip" class="InputNum" value="">'
// access your new input elem via temp.firstChild
```

3. On a similar note to #1, you shouldn't be trying to replace the contents of the custom button with your new input, you can either replace the button itself, or set it up as a toggle and just have the input be appended as a sibling.

Everything above would be implemented as:

```
<button aria-label="Custom" aria-selected="false" class="ButtonContainer" onclick="swap(this)">Custom</button>

<script>
function swap(buttonElem) {
  const temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = '<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" aria-describedby="error-tip" class="InputNum" value="">' 
    buttonElem.replaceWith(temp.firstChild)
}
</script>
```